# Nodejs Sql data fetching

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, node.js

i am completely new guy to node js. i got the sql results form my database with following code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.get("/",function(req,res){
var client = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database:'Arun'
});

client.query(
   'SELECT PersonID FROM Persons WHERE City="chennai"',
   function (err, results, fields) { 
       res.send(results);
       client.end();            
    });        
});

app.listen(8080);
```

The above code gives result like this

```
[{"PersonID":1}]
```

But i need only the value 1. how to print this value to html table. pls guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{"PersonId":1} is a JSON and you can access its value as follows:

```
var results = JSON.parse(results);
results[0]["PersonID"];
```

and then you can append this value in your table using jquery.

Comment: results[0]["PersonId"] ,results[0]["PersonID"] both are not working

Comment: try: var results = JSON.parse(results);

and then

results[0]["PersonID"]